# Reading data where one column has numeric values with spaces

Tags: r

So I have a csv file and the contents of it look like this.

```
dat1 = data.frame(val = c("21,303 ", "21,000 ", 
                         "23,000 ", 200, 100, 200))
dat1
```

There are basically tabs/spaces at the end of some of the values in the val column.

When I import that data into R using fread or read_csv, it produces a result like this, whereby everything is a character value and \t was added to the column

```
dat2 = data.frame(val = c("\t21,303", "\t21,000", "\t23,000", 
                         "200", "100", "200"))
dat2
```

Just doing a basic import command

```
dat = fread("")
dat = readr::read_csv("")
```

Any idea on how I can get the data into R give that the column has a tab/space and numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this efficient way using data.table.

```
data.table::setDT(dat2)
dat2[,val:=as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:] ]", "", val))]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use gsub to remove anything that is a non-digit:

```
dat$val <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D","",dat$val))
```

This will find anything that is not a digit and delete it from the string.

This outputs:

```
1    21303
2    21000
3    23000
...
```

Answer (score 2):

That "\t" is a representation of a tab. You have many options.

One of the easiest one is to run a gsub.

```
dat2$val <- as.numeric(gsub("[\t]","", dat2$val))
```

Comment: While this will work for OP, a more exhaustive approach would have used "\\D" since we only want to retain digits. if another reader has a similar problem, your answer is pretty tailored to this one specific problem while "\\D" would work for anyone who wants to only retain the numbers.

Comment: Indeed "\\D" would retain only numbers. 
Nonetheless, I wrapped the gsub within an "as.numeric", that would return NA's in case an observation has other non-numeric characters.

Comment: I see. Do you think that offers some additional value? I am unsure why getting NAs is preferable.

Comment: Well, in fact it all depends on how does the user want to handle errors or unexpected observations. 
While "\\D" whould be more exhaustive for users confident that their observations' only valuable strings are numbers, as.numeric("[\t]"...) would be more tailored to tabs and conservative of other alfanumeric noises, "\\s" would be more exhaustive for all types of spaces (tabs, carriage returns, spacebar, end of line).